# Expresión regular: rango letras y números

Tags: regex

Necesito crear una expresión regular pero no me queda espero me puedan ayudar.
La expresión solo debe permitir los siguientes caracteres:

- De la letra `A-H` en minúsculas y mayúsculas.
- De la letra `J-N` en minúsculas y mayúsculas.
- La letra `p` mayúsculas y minúscula.
- De la letra `R-Z` en minúsculas y mayúsculas.
- Y número del `0-9`.

Esto es lo que llevo pero no me funciona:

```
([A-H][a-h][J-N][j-n][P][p][R-Z][r-z][0-9])\w+
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías colocar un ejemplo de una cadena que haga match con lo que pides? Porque tal y como lo necesitas entiendo que es lo siguiente: `[j-nJ-N][a-hA-H][pP][r-zR-Z][0-9]`. De esta manera `jaPr0` vale pero no `zaPr0` siguiendo el orden que comentas. Además de no saber la longitud que debe tener y si alguno de ellos se puede o no repetir.

Comment: La longitud no me la da pero el ejemplo sería algo asi: "LJCPCBLCX11000237"

Comment: Toma, aprende aquí: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Si no te piden una longitud en específico, se permite sí y solo sí, cualquiera de las condiciones pedidas en cualquier orden, entonces valdría lo siguiente: `[j-nJ-N]|[a-hA-H]|[pP]|[r-zR-Z]|[0-9]`. Lee el resultado de la regex en https://regex101.com/ en el cuadro de la derecha.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que en otras palabras esta expresión debe aceptar los números del cero al nueve y las letras de la a a la zeta, en mayúsculas y minúsculas, excepto por la i, la o y la q. Siguiendo con la idea de definir clases puedes usar esta expresión:

```
exp=/^[a-hj-npr-z0-9]+$/ig
```

Lo que le faltaba a tu ejemplo era usar el inicio y el fin de la cadena, o sea, `^` y `$` respectivamente. De esta forma la expresión rechazará cualquier cadena que contenga los caracteres excluidos.

La otra parte importante es simplificar la distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas usando los modificadores `/ig` que ignoran globalmente la distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! me funciono a la perfección. Saludos.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya ayudado. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes definir una clase con los caracteres que necesitas:
`[a-hA-Hj-nJ-NpPr-zR-Z0-9]`
Y luego especificas si quieres que existan de 0 a mas caracteres con '*':
`[a-hA-Hj-nJ-NpPr-zR-Z0-9]*`
O de 1 a mas caracteres con '+':
`[a-hA-Hj-nJ-NpPr-zR-Z0-9]+`
O si quieres minimo 3 caracteres y maximo 8 caracteres pues podrias hacerlo:
`[a-hA-Hj-nJ-NpPr-zR-Z0-9]{3,8}`, puedes reemplazar el 3 y el 8 por los caracteres minimos y maximos que necesecites.